# ASP.NET - Impersonating users except when accessing SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, iis, impersonation

Given the following architecture which I probably cannot change:

- **Application** - ASP.NET MVC + Entity Framework, running on IIS
- **Database** - SQL Server, permissions granted to a single specific domain user that runs the app pool in IIS
- **Remote Service** - Needs actual user credentials (not the app pool user)

When enabling Windows Authentication + Impersonation in IIS, and setting Integrated Security=true in the connection string, all database requests use the impersonated user's credentials and fail, because users don't have permissions on the database.

I'm looking for a way to impersonate users when accessing the remote service but use the app pool user when accessing the database through Entity Framework, without having to put the username and password in the connection string.